# Propagate Environment Variable via a Batch File?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, batch-file, environment-variables

I am setting some permanent environment variables via a batch file. Is it possible to propagate them without logging off via a batch file? I have seen [this reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104011) but would like to know if it is possible via a batch file as well.

Currently, when I set the environment variables (with Visual Studio closed) and fire up Visual Studio, the new environment variables are not recognized and a given project (which depends on the variables) fails to compile. If I log-off then log back on, they are. The same is the case if I want the batch file to detect whether the variable exists and if it does, do nothing.

Unless I log-off/on, when the batch file sets the environment variable, does its job and closes, if I re-run it, it will set the variable again (fails to detect that it already exists). If I log-off/on, then the batch file detects the variable (and informs the user) and Visual Studio compiles the given project without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I can follow this.  Environment variable values are only ever inherited from the process that starts a new process.  When you set them in a .bat or .cmd file, you are altering *only* the variable values of the cmd.exe process that executes the batch file.

If you then start devenv.exe from that *same* cmd.exe session then Visual Studio will have those altered/added environment variables as well.

What does *not* work is starting Visual Studio from Explorer.  That got started way back when you logged in.  It got initialized with the system environment.  Which you can modify with the Control Panel + System applet.  Advanced, Environment variables button.  To make the changes here effective, you have to *restart* a process so it gets initialized with these altered settings.

Which in effect means that you have to restart Explorer.  Yes, logging out does that.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I can restart the explorer with the user's consent. Thanks!

Comment: On trying that out, I found that even after setting the environment variable via SETX and then restarting explorer.exe and then Visual Studio, the environment variable was NOT detected. A Log-off/on cycle was needed.

Comment: I'm going to have to guess that you didn't completely kill Explorer.

Comment: Completely kill Explorer? Just killing the explorer.exe process and restarting it is not enough?

Comment: Completely, no Start button, no taskbar.  Logging out is obviously the easier approach.

Comment: :( thanks for the replies, I will mark this answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

> **Problem:**  You set persistent environment variables in your .bat file and are wondering if you can run Visual C++ without logging off /
> recycling explorer ?

So you are using SETX to create persistent environment variables from inside a .bat file.  if you then inside the same bat file use SET to set the same Environment Values for the local cmd shell then they will be useable immediately from the local cmd shell.

Then create another batch file to start Visual C++ and use it to start visual C++ from the same shell you ran your original .bat file from.
To bring Visual C++ up from the command like you type [start devenv].

I'm not sure of your workflow but the trade off is you have have both setx and a mirror set for each environment variable in your batch file, against relogging on or remembering to cycle your cmdshell or explorer process.

If the batch file is a write once and forget, I'd think about the setx/set solution.